# Python code does not respond after running the following code:

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am making a virtual assistant using speech recognition and default Microsoft voices. The code runs without any error, but gets stuck at "Listening.....". After this, the code doesn't take any input from my side and freezes.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishme():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >=0 and hour<=12:
        speak("GOOD MORNING!!!")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("GOOD AFTERNOON")

    else:
        speak("good evening")

    speak("i am koro !! sir please tell me how may i help you")


def takeCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening........")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)


    try:
        print("Recognizing.....")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("user said: {}".format(query))

    except Exception as e:
         print(e)

        print("say that again please.......")
        return "None"
    return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # speak("harry is a good boy")
   wishme()
   takeCommand()
```

Comment: It listens until it hears a phrase. Is it possible that it's simply not hearing anything? You can supply a `timeout` argument, though that's probably not useful for you right now if you do want to wait until it hears something.

Comment: what you say try and except blocks are with proper indentation and you can use r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) just below with statement to eliminate noise